# How to include all json parsed image urls inside img src tag to display all of them in Blogger

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, blogger

Hi I have a situation here ; I am trying to publish to blogger using Google app script with attachment images , so far i got all the images through the json parse which is images urls but passing them to blogger doesn't work , and i found a way to pass the images through the

I got the json response as urls of facebook photos ;

the parsed response js code here as follows

```
 var medias =attachment.data[0].subattachments
 var i = 0; 
 for (i = 0; i <10 ; i++){
 var album =medias.data[i].media.image.src
var imass= album
Logger.log(imass); 
}
```

The problem is with the passing of urls to blogger through the Api 
This is the blogger APi code ,

```
 var kind ='#blogger#post';


var blogId = BLOG_ID

var Featuredimagez = firstimage 

var content =content 

// imass =attached imageurls

   var imgbody = "<img  src=\""+Featuredimagez+"\">"+content+"<img 
  src=\""+imass+"\">"


 var body = JSON.stringify({
  'kind': kind,
 'blog': {
  'id': blogId
 },
'title': title,
'content': imgbody,
"images": [
  {
   "url": imass
  }
 ],




 });
```

Using this method I got the last image from the parsed json urls

How to include all my urls inside the img src to display all images inside blog content without writing so many imgsrc tags ?